# Taking the mean of a row of a pandas dataframe with NaN and arrays

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Here is my reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'x' : [np.NaN, np.array([0,2])], 'y' : [np.array([3,2]),np.NaN], 'z' : [np.array([4,5]),np.NaN], 't' : [np.array([3,4]),np.array([4,5])]})
```

I would like to compute the mean array for each row excluding NaN

I have tried `df.mean(axis=1)` which gives NaN for both row. This is particularly surprising to me as `df.sum(axis=1)` appears to be working as I would have expected.

`[df.loc[i,:].mean() for i in df.index]` does work but I am sure there is a more straightforward solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```
df.apply(lambda x: np.mean(x[x.notnull()]), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0    [3.3333333333333335, 3.6666666666666665]
1                                  [2.0, 3.5]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Faster way to do the same thing: `df.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().mean(), axis=1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your DataFrame uses the `object` dtype which is always a bit of a bodge.  It's slower than native types, and doesn't always behave the way you'd expect.

Since Pandas removed the "Panel" type which was used for 3D data, I'd recommend you not store this data in a DataFrame.  Instead, store it in a 3D NumPy array, then you can use `np.nanmean()` to easily calculate averages while ignoring NaN.

Comment: Actually that wouldn't fit in a numpy array as the subarrays don't have the same number of items. You can use a MultiIndex to act as nd-arrays with pandas.

Comment: @mozway The subarrays all have two elements except for the NAN ones.  So OP should just use `[NaN, NaN]` instead of single `NaN`.